# 「想い人」 and 「恋人」?

Tags: word-choice, nuances

Dictionary definitions from my EDICT based dictionary.

> 想い人​【おもいびと】(n) loved one; lover; sweetheart
>
> 恋人​【こいびと】(n)  lover; sweetheart

I was wondering, since these definitions are nearly the same, are there any differences in nuance and etc between these (other than how the latter is more common as far as I'm aware)?

Comment: http://okwave.jp/qa/q6209253.html - potentially helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

想い人​ is the one you're in love with. The one might not be in love with you.
恋人​ is the one you're dating.

Comment: Note that 想い人 is a literary/poetic expression. In everyday conversations, people almost always use 好きな人 instead.